# Smalltalk syntax highlighting for Latex

Tags: listings, syntax

What is the easiest way to format Smalltalk syntax using the listings package?

Comment: As a minimum, please include a reference to the Smalltalk syntax. Note that the [`listings` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) describe these customizations in detail in the [manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf). Care to share what you've done so far?

Comment: Did you already [google for it](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=listings+smalltalk+latex)?  E.g. http://marianopeck.wordpress.com/2012/06/17/smalltalk-syntax-highlighting-for-latex/

Comment: http://wiki.squeak.org/squeak/409 is a rather complete smalltalk grammar. A syntax highlighter for smalltalk is included in the latest images on http://www.pharo-project.org/home

Answer (score 4):

In the comment some hints are given. The following page provides some examples:

http://marianopeck.wordpress.com/2012/06/17/smalltalk-syntax-highlighting-for-latex/

To customize the given style have a look at the manual: [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings)